# I have the gist of baking normals but some details don't transfer

Tags: texture-baking

I learned how to bake normals today, I was able to transfer the gashes without a problem.

Scracthes don't appear though. What I am most curious about however is how to get these rectangles and circles present on the bake too.

How does baking normals in blender work from the ground up?

I really want to incorporate this technique into my creative pipeline.

[image: Some of the baking settings I used]

[image: It seems as if they were read by blender and slightly implemented?]

[image: The rectangles and circles I want to bake]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably due to the fact that the faces that you're trying to bake are perpendicular or parallel to the faces that are baking. Baking the normals save the tilt (orientation) of the baked face, not its height. A perpendicular or parallel face can't be baked. In image 1 there's nothing to bake. In image 2, the tilted faces can be baked:

[image]

Comment: I had thought about this last night, your answer really helps me sum it up, I appreciate you!